# Hidden spaces/tabs pushing content down

Tags: html, css

This happened recently and I don't really know what is causing this. Some pages are fine so I tried copying the codes over to those files affected and the content is pushed down, two files with same code and one of them is pushed down. I thought maybe it could be the file format so I tried changing encoding to UTF-8, UTF-8 without BOM, ANSI. Using notepad++, CodeIgniter, XAMPP 3.1.0.3.1.0.

This is what I mean
http://i37.tinypic.com/2cletz.png

It should be like this
http://i33.tinypic.com/2ypnpjp.png

Appears in quotation when inspecting elements in Chrome(able to delete by clicking delete node and it is becomes fine)
http://i36.tinypic.com/30bhchz.png

Appears as spaces/tabs when viewing source in IE
http://i37.tinypic.com/2dj76fk.png

A simple HTML code like this can cause this problem

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

</head>

<body link="#294052" vlink="#294052" alink="grey" font="verdana" style="width:1407px">

<div id="header" style="height:100px;width:1407px;background-color:#294052;">

<div id="img" style="float:left;">
<img src="/e-com/images/logo.jpg" style="margin-left:130%;" />
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing whitespace between html-tags will probably fix your problem.

Secondly, do you have any css like this  `html,body { margin:0px; padding:0px }`? This will remove the white border around your page.

Lastly, your example with `Chrome` states a `title` tag in the body, which is not in the code (note: titles should be in the `head`).

Comment: The title tag was not displayed because there was no new line between  text and code in my post. I have added    margin:0px;    and this didn't fix the problem. I also checked for spaces at the end of each line and there were none.

Comment: With [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eFfBh/) I cannot reproduce your whiteline. However, by using my line above I can remove the white border (notice the extra styling on `body`).